# Connecting to an Access database

Tags: visual-c++

I need a little help here! I am trying to connect to a local Access file with this code;

```
public: Void connectTodatabase()
    {
        //creating and opening the database
        OleDbConnection ^myTICLConnection = gcnew     OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data     Source=C:\Users\LOVE\Documents\CLERKS.accdb;User ID=Admin;NewValue=Bad");
        myTICLConnection->Open();
    }
```

. . . and this is the error I get.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Could not find file 'C:\Users\LOVE\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\REPLACEMENT\REPLACEMENT\UsersLOVEDocumentsCLERKS.accdb'.

NB: I have already declared the Data and OleDb namespaces.
I just can't figure out what the issue is.

PLEASE HELP!!